# Async task don't change external variable. Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I can't save data from URL, because function in infinit loop. How fix it?
My code:

```
func getRegion2(){
    let method = "region/"

    var url = serviceUrl+method
    var myArray: [String]()
    while(url != nil){

        Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):

                let nextUrl = JSON(data)["next"].stringValue
                url = nextUrl
                myArray = myArray + myArray
                print(nextUrl)

            case .failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    print(myArray)
}
```

If run without the "while", then everything works fine.

Comment: Why you used while ? What is your purpose ?

Comment: Block is async. So, you have to check at `myArray = myArray + myArray` this line. Do print after this line.

Comment: @emresancaktar I use "while" because i don't know how many time need to execute Alamofire.request(url). First step: download data from default url. Save array from data and check nextUrl. Step two: If nextUrl not nil then download data from nextUrl and add array and etc.

Comment: Search on "asynchronous".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to combine a recursive function and a dispatch group (not tested):

```
func getRegion2(){
    let method = "region/"

    var url = serviceUrl+method
    var myArray: [String] = []

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    func getRegion(with url: String) {
        group.enter()
        Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):

                let nextUrl = JSON(data)["next"].stringValue
                myArray = myArray + someArrayFromRespnse
                print(nextUrl)

                if nextUrl != nil {
                    getRegion(with: nextUrl)
                }

                group.leave()
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    getRegion(with: url)

    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { 
        print(myArray)
    }
}
```

I would use a completionBlock:

```
func getRegion2(completion: () -> [String]?) {
    let method = "region/"
    var url = serviceUrl+method
    var myArray: [String] = []

    func getRegion(with url: String) {
        Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):

                let nextUrl = JSON(data)["next"].stringValue
                myArray = myArray + someArrayFromRespnse
                print(nextUrl)

                if nextUrl != nil {
                    getRegion(with: nextUrl)
                } else {
                    completion(myArray)
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }

    getRegion(with: url)
}
```

Comment: Happy to help !